# assign device to dhcp scope

Tags: dhcp

one dhcp server running server 2003 r2, 2 dhcp scopes, is it possible to assign a static lease to a device by mac address to use the 2nd scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes totally, unfold the second scope, you will see a "reservations" category, when you add a host, you will have a field 'Mac Address', just type the MAC address and the ip you want to assign, 
Nb : the mac has to be entered without the colons  : 005056c00008

Comment: i added the reservation to the 2nd scope, but the device got the dhcp lease from the first

Comment: you can either add another reservation for the scop (but it's useless if you need just one ip) so try this link : 
http://www.petri.co.il/filter-mac-address-windows-server-2008-dhcp-server-callout-dll.htm

and if you an't be able to go throught it, you can simply set a manual ip to the server

Comment: i had looked at the callout dll but nothing i have read indicates that i can exclude the address from just one scope, both scopes are on the same server.